# Displaying data from a oracle sql table graphically

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I have programmatically created a chart using ASP.Net, now I just need to figure out how to connect to an oracle sql developer database and retrieve the data to populate the chart.

Would I use an OleDb method (see below), along with some other logic?

```
      using System.Data.OleDb;
      OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection;();
      myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
      myConnection.Open();
      //execute queries, etc
      myConnection.Close();
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you filling a dataset/table and are you using raw sql or a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

http://justins-fat-tire.blogspot.com/

I've got some code examples that show how to use a stored procedure to fill a dataset/table and get a generic List of object data.  If you're using raw sql you will need to modify the command object a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a DataTable as the data source for the chart. To do this, you first need to populate the table.

```
public void Populate()
{
    Datatable data = GetData();

    foreach(DataRow r in data.Rows)
    {
        /// Populate chart using data
    }
}

public DataTable GetData()
{
    try
    {
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection;();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();

    //Set commandtype and text here.
    myCommand.CommandType = SOMETYPE;
    myCommand.CommandText = "SOMETEXT";

    OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    t.Load(reader);

    return t;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```